# Increase EBS Volume size of AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I want to increase 80 GB Storage of AWS  Lightsail max plan. Can I increase that?

Comment: Please explain negative vote so that i can make changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

As of November 2017, you can now attach up to 15 additional disks to an instance. These are EBS General Purpose SSD (gp2) volumes, priced around $0.10 per GB-month.

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/820465/aws-attach-ebs-to-lightsail-instance

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to increase the storage in the max plan. Unlike EC2, in Lightsail you have to upgrade the bundle to get more storage and you are already at the maximum bundle.

```
aws lightsail get-bundles
```

lists your bundle as the max. So there is no way to increase the storgae beyond 80GB. You have to choose EC2 service for your needs. Lightsail is not the solution for your needs. At this time, there is no way to launch an EC2 instance from your Lightsail snapshots.